# Spring boot: Rebuild EntityManagerfactory at Runtime

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, byte-buddy

I'm trying to build a multi-tenant object management platform for an ERP system in which entities are specific to each tenants. I'm generating entities at runtime using **bytebuddy** once after I load them to the class path, I need to rebuild the **emf** at runtime by adding the newly generated entities. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: I assume you are trying to regenerate the classes and dropping the old ones. You would want to load all objects in a different class loader in this case and through away the old class loader once you regenerate them.

Comment: Yes, I'll regenerate classes when the user adds /removes fields, I'm thinking of creating different versions of the class by appending version numbers to the class name and load them to the existing class loader instead of creating a different class loader. I wanted to know is there anyway to recreate **entitymanagerfactory** and replace all the existing reference to the **emf** with the newly created object. I've tried adding `@RefreshScope` to emf configuration class. But it didn't work.

Comment: You would need to generate a proxy that delegates to the factory that is currently valid. You cannot change the shape of a loaded class. I would also recommend you class loader isolation to allow for unloading unused classes where you will otherwise quickly pollute your heap.